# Design help for thread synchronization

Tags: python, multithreading, synchronization

I am writing a python program which validates device events.

I am continuosly reading some data from serial port from a device. When I write something on serail port of device, the device writes a string on serialport which I have to read. Continously reading part from serial port is in a seperate worker thread an I read it line by line and write it to a thread. The device writes some data continuously and also it writes the event description on the serail port.

To be more specific when I write something on the device, it generates an event on the device. The description of the event is written back to the serial port. This i have to read it back and validate whether the event has occured.

Now what is happening as I am reading device output line by line in a thread, by the time i write something and start reading that event desc to occur, the output of that has already gone and next some other output line are being read. How do I synchronize this?

Can any help me in designing this part?

Comment: Do you have any small code snippets of what you are doing right now? If you are continuously reading from the device, then there should be no way to "miss" a line.

Comment: Also, does this reading and writing process need to be two independent threads for a reason? It sounds like a request-response system for a single thread. Is it supposed to be async where at some later time the reader will validate the posted event, and the writer can keep moving along?

Comment: Code Snippet is as follows:

Class SerialCom:

     __init__(self,comport):
         self.comport = comport
         self.readSerialPortThread = ReadSearialPortThread(self.comport)
     
      def writeStringToSerialPort():
  
         self.comport.write(somedata)

Answer (score 0):

If you are just using threads for asynchronous IO, You may be better off not using threads and use select.select, or perhaps even asyncore if you want to make it even easier on yourself.

http://docs.python.org/library/asyncore.html

Answer (score -1):

Code Snippet is as follows:

Class SerialCom:

```
 __init__(self,comport):

     self.comport = comport

     self.readSerialPortThread = ReadSearialPortThread(self.comport)

  def writeStringToSerialPort(someString):

     self.comport.write(someString)

  def waitfordata(someString):

    #I have to continuously read data from serial port till we someString.
```

In ReadSearialPortThread data from serialport is continuously reading device info values. When I write data using writeStringToSerialPort(), the device outputs some data to the serial port I have to read this data from the function waitfordata, to validate the response from the device.

Now what is happening is when I write some values and call waitfordata() the required value are already read by readSerialPortThread and continued to reading some other values like device info. So I am losing the values there. I want to know how to syncronize that.

Comment: Please use the *Post answer* button only for actual answers. You should modify your original question to add additional information.